# Nodes near coords formatting is incorrect when non-default sci formatting is specified

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, nodes-near-coords

Upon showing some `nodes near coords` in my plots I stumbled upon a formatting issue related to the use of `/pgf/number format/sci generic` options.

More specifically, when changing the default mantissa with

```
\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}]\pgfplotspointmeta
```

The exponent is missing.

I checked the behavior directly in pure Ti*kZ* output, but this works fine.
The problem only seems to show up in `pgfplots`. At first I thought this would be a precision issue since I ran into this problem with very small values, but even with standard (around unit) values, it shows up.

Does anybody have a clue on a workaround/patch for this ?

**EDIT : Clarification for solution selection**

- An alternative proposal was indicated by [Ulrike Fischer here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54794687#54794687), specifically

```
sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\cdot,exponent={10^{####1}}}
```

which shows that there are multiple intricate levels in this call.

- While I first did not consider using a style as proposed in the accepted solution, Ulrike Fischer also advised for this approach, hence the accepted proposal.

Here is a MWE showing the issue and some tests.

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,width=5cm,height=5cm}
\begin{document}
Correct output in pure TikZ

\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}]{12.345}

\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}]{12.345e-8}

Correct output in pgfplots with only "nodes near coords"

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords,domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Correct output in pgfplots with "nodes near coords" with sci formatting and "$\cdot$" (default) mantissa separator

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci]\pgfplotspointmeta},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Wrong output in pgfplots with "nodes near coords" with sci formatting and manually set "$\cdot$" mantissa separator

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\cdot,exponent={10^{#1}}}]\pgfplotspointmeta},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Wrong output in pgfplots with "nodes near coords" with sci formatting and "$\times$" mantissa separator

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}]\pgfplotspointmeta},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found if you define the style via `\tikzset` and use it as the option for `\pgfmathprintnumber` the output will be correct. But I don't know why.

To format the number format, you can also use package `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,width=5cm,height=5cm}
    \tikzset{
       /pgf/number format/scinum/.style={
         sci,
         sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{##1}}},
         },
      }
\begin{document}
Correct output in pure TikZ

\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}]{12.345}

\pgfmathprintnumber[sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}]{12.345e-8}

Correct output in pgfplots with only "nodes near coords"


Wrong output in pgfplots with "nodes near coords" with sci formatting and "$\times$" mantissa separator

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[scinum]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\num[scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, this observation about style definition is very interesting. I will check if it works on my code later.

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason: the content of `nodes near coords` is passed to `nodes near coords*`, and `nodes near coords*` is defined as

```
        /pgfplots/nodes near coords*/.style={%
            /pgfplots/scatter/true*,%
            /pgfplots/set point meta if empty=f(x),%
            scatter/@post marker code/.append code={%
                % ok, place the node.
                \t@pgfplots@tokb=\expandafter{\pgfplots@current@point@coordinatestyle}% see 'coordinate style'%
                \edef\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{%
                    /pgfplots/nodes near coords/@@eval alignment,%
                    \the\t@pgfplots@tokb,%
                    /pgfplots/every node near coord%
                }%
                \expandafter\node\expandafter[\pgfplots@loc@TMPa]%
                {%
                    \if1\csname pgfpmeta@\pgfplotspointmetainputhandler @issymbolic\endcsname%
                        % point meta=explicit symbolic
                        % do not try to invoke \pgfmathprintnumber on
                        % symbolic data... this check should keep the user
                        % interface simpler.
                        \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPa{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}%
                        \def\pgfplots@loc@TMPb{##1}%
                        \ifx\pgfplots@loc@TMPa\pgfplots@loc@TMPb
                            \pgfplotspointmeta
                        \else
                            ##1%
                        \fi
                    \else
                        ##1%
                    \fi
                };
            },%
        },%
```

So `#1` in `exponent={10^{#1}}` is not expanded correctly because of the outer wrapper  of `nodes near coords*`.

I fail to figure out where is wrong. But there is a work around: set the key outside like

```
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\cdot,exponent={10^{#1}}}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17,width=5cm,height=5cm}
\newcommand{\sciset}[1]{\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{#1}}

\begin{document}
Correct output in pgfplots with "nodes near coords" with sci formatting and manually set "$\cdot$" mantissa separator

\sciset{sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\cdot,exponent={10^{#1}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Correct output in pgfplots with "nodes near coords" with sci formatting and "$\times$" mantissa separator

\sciset{sci,sci generic={mantissa sep=\times,exponent={10^{#1}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},domain=0:1,samples=5] {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, but your work around does not seem to work on my system. Can you show an output ?

Comment: I have changed my answer. Note that it is the global setting.

Comment: Yes, I guess it works too well ... unfortunately I need it do only be focused on the `nodes near coords` formattin. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I try to hack the code of `nodes near coordinates` by `xpatch` and `/pgfplots/scatter/@pre marker code`, but failed.

Comment: Do not worry to much, I think an issue in the `pgfplots` tacker is in order